# Which of these are tautologies in First-Order Logic?

Tags: first-order-logic

1. $Fx\lor\neg Fx$
2. $Fa\supset Fa$
3. $(a=a)\land\neg(a=b)$

My guess is that only #2 is a tautology. #1 is not a tautology because there can be multiple variable assignments?

Comment: You can have many variable assigments, but **each** one of them will assign to $x$ the same value. Thus, for every variable assignment $s$ we will have that either $Fx[s]$ is true or $\lnot Fx[s]$ is. Thus, the formula is *valid*.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming F is a predicate, it must either be true or false for any variable assignment. Therefore, #1 is also a tautology in classical logic (called the *law of excluded middle*).